# Can I store files in Onedrive offline only

Tags: onedrive, offline-files

Is it possible to use Onedrive as storage only, I need to upload photos from my computer to OneDrive, then I need to delete them locally from my pc in order to save harddrive space. But the photos uploaded to Onedrive must be kept on OneDrive Cloud so that I can download them to another computer at a later time.

Comment: You can directly upload it to onedrive using browser and not sync it to your PC. I am not sure you can use the onedrive synced folder to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, OneDrive can do this. This features is called “OneDrive Files On-Demand”. You can learn more about the details [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-onedrive-files-on-demand-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e).

Basically, it goes like this:

1. Enable Files On-Demand on OneDrive settings

   - Note how the OneDrive folder view changes in Explorer
2. Bring up the context menu on the files/folders you want to remove from your PC
3. Select “Free up space”

   - The file/folder status icon will change to a cloud, indicating this file/folder is currently not synced to your PC

You need at least Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (1709) and the latest OneDrive client.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I'll enable "Files on demand" and then upload the files using the browser to my onedrive. That way the files will be in the cloud until I download them from any of my PC. This will work just the way I want it :)

Comment: You don’t need to use the browser to upload. Just put the files in the desired place, wait until OneDrive has finished syncing and then “Free up space”.